# 'Cannot determine link language for target...' issue in sub directory

Tags: cmake, codeblocks

In the main folder of my project, I have a CMakeLists.txt file.  Inside this file, I include (using *add_subdirectory*) another CMakeLists.txt file located in my header file directory.  The responsibility of this second file is to add all of my header files to the project:

```
file(GLOB gl_nbody_HEADERS "*.h")

add_executable(gl_nbody ${gl_nbody_HEADERS})
```

However, this files causes an error:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:gl_nbody
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "gl_nbody".
```

What is strange is that when I include the two lines causing this error in my main *CMakeLists.txt* file (modified to work correctly for the change in directory), it works fine.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`add_executable` causes the creation of an executable target, meaning the compilation of a list of source code files into an executable binary.

In order for this to work, and have CMake select a suitable compiler, the list of source files must contain at least one file with a "compilable" extension, ie. .c, or .cpp, or .cxx....

I don't see why you are trying to compile an executable here, since you only seem to try to list header files for inclusion into a project (which only makes sense for IDE-based generators, such as Visual Studio).

Also, it is not recommended to use globbing of files in CMake, because if you add more files to your project, CMake cannot detect them automatically, and will not regenerate build files. Please list all files explicitely.

The proper solution here is to list the header files in the proper `add_executable` command call where you list the actual source files that you want to compile.

You might also want to use the [source_group()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/source_group.html) command, that allows you to group files into folders in the generated Visual Studio solution, for example:

```
source_group(header_files ${gl_nbody_HEADERS})
```